# Possible to get word cadidates from Windows's in-built IME?

Tags: winapi, ime

Windows 10 has touch keyboards which can be activated by right-clicking the Taskbar and select "Show touch keyboard button" and then click the keyboard icon. Below is a screenshot of typing some text on Notepad using Windows 10's in-built English touch keyboard. It shows word completion candidates as I type (I only typed 'a', and it shows "am").

Can I programmatically get those completion candidates when the touch keyboard is not visible? What I would like to do do is show an auto completion drop-down menu (like the one you see in Visual Studio) with those candidates and when the user hits tab, input the selected candidate. I wonder if Microsoft exposes some sort of API for getting text candidates, something like,

```
GetTextCandidate("I a");
returns: {"am", "also", "agree", "already",...}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is IMM API: [`ImmGetCandidateList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imm/nf-imm-immgetcandidatelista).

You can refer to related official sample: [Windows-classic-samples/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/input/ime](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/1d363ff4bd17d8e20415b92e2ee989d615cc0d91/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/input/ime).

More references: [About Input Method Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/about-input-method-manager) and [Candidate Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/candidate-lists).

Comment: This is NOT for getting the conversion candidates in CJK languages like Japanese (しゅうせい --> 修正, 集成, 終世...), but for getting input completion candidates (a -> am, also, agree) in Western European languages like English?

Comment: @DamnVegetables Got what you mean. I'll do a further investigation.

Comment: @DamnVegetables There is no out of box API can achieve your purpose. Touch keyboard you have already seen it is a application implement this function for non-East Asian language like English. So you may need implement this auto complete function by yourself.